# Select Box alignment differ in chrome and mozilla

Tags: html, css

[image]

Selectbox font differ from chrome and mozilla. It is correctly aligning in Mozilla. But not in chrome

CSS

```
 select {
    -moz-appearance: none;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url("../img/select-arrow.png") no-repeat scroll 90% center;
    border: 0 none !important;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) inset;
    color: #000;
    height: 22px;
    padding: 0;
    text-indent: 0.01px;
    text-overflow: "";
    width: 67%;
}
```

Comment: Please share the code.

Comment: Share the css code you used for this.

Comment: set line height of the select box.

Comment: line-height:22px;

Comment: Maheswaran S - Yeah its Correct. Thanks